# Change FontSize on all labels autolayout

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout, uilabel, uifont

I have an issue that I can't seem to find a good answer for. Which is weird, since it should be a common issue. I'm using xcode 6, and autolayout. I set up my views with constraints using width x height as Any x Any. I have designed my layout based on iPhone 6 (4.7inch), but should support iPhone 5 (4 inch) as well. Everything layouts fine - except text in labels and buttons.

I can't for the life of me figure out why the text does not get autoresized throughout the app when it clearly have to in order to fit inside respective buttons and labels.

I tried settings properties

```
[button.titleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
[button.titleLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:0.5f];
```

Which fixed the issue, but now every button and label has different fontSize since they are all considering different containers where the length of the text impacts if it needs to be resized or not.

Anyone got any ideas on how I can dynamically change the fontSize throughout the app using autolayout?

Comment: @ClockWise- hey did you get an answer for this? Am trying to do the same, please let me know

Comment: @z22 sorry, not really. Was a while back now, but I think I skipped using the two methods above since I couldn't get it working, and just made sure my font size fit on all resolutions :/